# Reading data dynamically from XML using LINQ to XML

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-xml

I need to read XML doc looking like example below (short version)

```
<root>
 <data>
    <_0>
        <id>123</id>
        <status>complete</status>
        <datesubmitted>2014-07-07 10:35:45</datesubmitted>
        <question1>10</question1>
        <question2>Yes</question2>
        <question3></question3>
    </_0>
    <_1>
        <id>456</id>
        <status>complete</status>
        <datesubmitted>2014-07-07 11:05:45</datesubmitted>
        <question1>10</question1>
        <question2>Yes</question2>
        <question3></question3>
    </_1>
    <_2>
        <id>789</id>
        <status>complete</status>
        <datesubmitted>2014-07-07 12:15:45</datesubmitted>
        <question1>10</question1>
        <question2>Yes</question2>
        <question3></question3>
    </_2>
 </data>
</root>
```

By using suggestion posted here previously I was using LINQ to XML

```
XElement root = XElement.Load(@"c:\\Temp\\SurveyResponse.xml");

var data = from child in root.Elements("data").Elements()
                   select new
                   {
                       id = (int)child.Element("id"),
                       status = (string)child.Element("status"),
                       date = (string)child.Element("datesubmitted")

                   };
```

I have two questions
How to extract questions without hard coding it in the LINQ query statement

```
 question1 = (string)child.Element("question1"),
 question2 = (string)child.Element("question2"),
 question3 = (string)child.Element("question3"),
```

I need to have ability to build some kind question collection where questions going to be extracted with correct index. Note: question all sorted out but not necessarily begins from 1. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get list of questions as dictionary with question number as key. Question number can be extracted from node name using `substring` starting after position of "*n*" in "*question...*", for example :

```
var data = from child in doc.Root.Elements("data").Elements()
           select new
           {
               id = (int)child.Element("id"),
               status = (string)child.Element("status"),
               date = (string)child.Element("datesubmitted"),
               questions = child.Elements()
                                .Where(o => o.Name.LocalName.StartsWith("question"))
                                .ToDictionary(t => int.Parse(t.Name.LocalName.Substring(8)), 
                                              t => (string)t)
           };
```

This way you can get any question by it's number/index, for example :

```
var data1 = data.FirstOrDefault();
var question2 = data1.questions[2];
```